# Could o(n) efficiency be achieved for checking equality for two unordered sets in C?

Tags: c, performance, set

I know you can achieve o(n) in a sorted sets but I have looked around stackoverflow and couldn't find any answer that would be in o(n) efficiency, only o(n^2). Is there a way to achieve o(n) or is it impossible?

Comment: Sets of what data type?

Comment: Just signed 32 integers in arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the unordered sets have O(1) lookup (e.g. hash_maps) then you can iterate over set A, and for each item in set A, do a lookup in set B to see if it also contains the same item.  That results in O(n) for the full operation.

(Btw don't forget to check the sizes of the two sets first -- if they are different sizes, you know right away they are not equal, so return false)

Answer (score 2):

Consider 2 sets s0 and s1.  Checking for set membership should be fast like O(1) if the set is implemented as a hash (and also good with minimal collisions).

So, you can walk down s0 and for each element check s1 membership.  That's O(n).

However what if an element exists in s1 but not s0?  Just ensure the sets have equal size.